# What could cause an active TCP close to return without notifying the passive end?

Tags: tcp, rpc

I'm puzzled by the behavior of a TCP-using application. When the application at one end of an Internet-wide TCP connection calls close() on the socket, the close() returns. At the other end, however, the write() on the socket doesn't indicate that the TCP connection is closed. AFAIK, this behavior is inconsistent with the TCP specification: the active close() shouldn't return unless and until it receives an acknowledgement from the other end of the TCP connection (specifically, the TCP state at the active end can't transition out of TIME_WAIT_1 unless it receives an appropriate response from the other end -- at which point the write() at the other end should error-return).

I've seen this behavior when a malfunctioning Intrusion Prevention System (IPS) was between the ends of the TCP connection. The manufacturer of the IPS is addressing this problem.

Are there any other situations in which this behavior can occur?

My environment is Unix, C, ONC RPC, and sockets.

Comment: Are you sure the connection hasn't been closed, and the application just doesn't know about it until it does a `read()`/`write()` on it? Since the OS kernel ultimately manages the connections, the `close()` could in fact be working correctly, waiting for a response from the remote before returning. But then, the remote kernel knows the connection is closed but can't notify the application until it somehow tries to access that connection later... You'd have to trace packets to know for sure, I think...

Comment: @twalberg The passive-close end of the TCP connection is either within a write() system-call or will shortly call write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are conflating protocol state transitions and API behaviour. There is nothing in the RFCs that says the close() API can't return to the application and the protocol actions proceed asynchronously, and that is exactly what happens in the Sockets API by default. If there's pending data to be sent sitting in the socket send buffer and the receiver is slow it could take an arbitrary amount of time for the FIN to be sent. You can change that by setting a linger timeout with the socket option SO_LINGER, which causes close to block until all data has been flushed or the timeout expires, but it is hardly ever used in practice.

Comment: There's still something wrong. The client has no outstanding data to send to the server and the server's select() call on the socket consistently times-out rather than returning after the client's close() of the socket (the select() looks for read-ready only: it doesn't look for write-ready or exceptions).